# Storing some strings in a array

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I have this

```
sCSISmart1  TRAP-TYPE   
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                        
    VARIABLES {cycHostAdapterNumber, cycHostAdapterID, cycManagerID}          
    DESCRIPTION                             
    "SNMP Agent is up."                       
    --#TYPE "SNMP Agent is up."                    
    --#SUMMARY "SNMP Agent is up"                    
    --#ARGUMENTS {}                           
    --#SEVERITY INFORMATIONAL                       
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                  
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                    
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                          
    --#HELPTAG 101                    
::=  101
```

What I want to do

Some command to copy each name of `VARIABLE` into a array named `var`

**So output of above**

```
echo "${var[0]}"
cycHostAdapterNumber

echo "${var[1]}"
cycHostAdapterID

echo "${var[2]}"
cycManagerID
```

**Another example**

```
sCSISmart1  TRAP-TYPE   
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                        
    VARIABLES  { scellNameDateTime,                      
                     scellSWComponent,                     
                     scellECode,                  
                     scellCAC,                     
                     scellEIP}                           
    DESCRIPTION                             
    "SNMP Agent is up."                       
    --#TYPE "SNMP Agent is up."                    
    --#SUMMARY "SNMP Agent is up"                    
    --#ARGUMENTS {}                           
    --#SEVERITY INFORMATIONAL                       
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                  
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                    
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                          
    --#HELPTAG 101                    
::=  101
```

**Output for the above**

```
echo "${var[0]}"
scellNameDateTime

echo "${var[1]}"
scellSWComponent

echo "${var[2]}"
scellECode

echo "${var[3]}"
scellCAC

echo "${var[4]}"
scellEIP
```

**Another example**

```
sCSISmart1  TRAP-TYPE   
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                        
    VARIABLES  {                    
                     scellEIP
               }                           
    DESCRIPTION                             
    "SNMP Agent is up."                       
    --#TYPE "SNMP Agent is up."                    
    --#SUMMARY "SNMP Agent is up"                    
    --#ARGUMENTS {}                           
    --#SEVERITY INFORMATIONAL                       
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                  
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                    
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                          
    --#HELPTAG 101                    
::=  101
```

**Output for the above**

```
echo "${var[0]}"
scellEIP
```

What I have tried (All this does is store everything into `prvar`)

```
prvar="$(awk '/VARIABLES/,/}/ {gsub("VARIABLES"," "); gsub("}"," "); gsub("{"," ");gsub(","," ");print}' temp1)"
```

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure the names won't have spaces in them, remove the quotes and use `( )` around the command substitution:

```
prvar=($(awk ... temp1))
```

The effect:

```
$ prvar=( $(awk '/VARIABLES/,/}/ {gsub("VARIABLES"," "); gsub("}"," "); gsub("{"," ");gsub(","," ");print}' temp1) )
$ echo ${prvar[@]} ${#prvar[@]}
cycHostAdapterNumber cycHostAdapterID cycManagerID 3
```

Comment: I tried your command for some reason  `echo ${prvar[0]}` only prints `cycHo` and then I tried `echo ${prvar[@]} ${#prvar[@]}`  prints `cycHo tAdapterNumber cycHo tAdapterID cycManagerID 5` . Because I am not inputing it into `prvar` with `" "`  `s`  is not being printed.

Comment: @SamFlynn what does `od -c <<<"$IFS"` say?

Comment: `0000000   :       %   s  \n
0000005`

Comment: And why is your `IFS` set to `%s\n`?

Comment: Yeah I has set it to that before, when I was working on something else. Changed it to `IFS=","`. Okay now on `echo ${prvar[0]}` this is printed  `cycHostAdapterNumber  cycHostAdapterID  cycManagerID`

Comment: Set it to whatever your output will use to separate the names. If your output uses spaces, use that. If your output uses commas, then use `IFS=","`.

Comment: Okay I just changed `IFS="  "` and `echo ${prvar[0]}` prints correctly `cycHostAdapterNumber`

Comment: hey @muru can you tell me a way to store them without using the above method? I am to do the same thing else where on another type of a file. Or should I create another question?

Comment: @SamFlynn another question would be better.

Comment: Okay! Adding it in five minutes.

Comment: I have added the question @muru , I dont want to use the method above in solving this.  [Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/642693/add-particular-strings-to-an-array). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wanted to remove spaces from each array element, so I tried this `arrayvar=( $(awk '/'"$vovar"'/,/}/ {gsub("'"$vovar"'"," "); gsub("}"," "); gsub("{"," ");gsub(","," ");print}' temp1 | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed 's/[ \t]*$//') )` This However only removes spaces from `arrayvar[0]` . @muru Any idea how I can remove spaces in all the arrayvar elements?

Comment: @SamFlynn did you forget the `g` flag for `sed`? `sed 's/.../g'`?