# Add particular strings to an array sed/awk/grep

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-processing

I have this

```
ciscoFlashCopyStatus OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX  INTEGER
                {  
                copyOperationPending(0),
                copyInProgress(1),
                copyOperationSuccess (2),
                copyInvalidOperation (3),
                copyInvalidProtocol (4),
                copyInvalidSourceName (5),
                copyInvalidDestName (6),
                copyInvalidServerAddress (7),
                copyDeviceBusy (8),
                copyDeviceOpenError (9),
                copyDeviceError (10),
                copyDeviceNotProgrammable (11),
                copyDeviceFull (12),
                copyFileOpenError (13),
                copyFileTransferError(14),
                copyFileChecksumError(15),
                copyNoMemory (16),
                copyUnknownFailure(17),
                copyInvalidSignature(18)
                }
        MAX-ACCESS      read-only
        STATUS  current
```

What I want to do

Some command to copy each name of `VARIABLE` into a array named `var`

So example of output

```
echo "${var[0]}
copyOperationPending

echo "${var[1]}
copyInProgress

echo "${var[2]}
copyOperationSuccess

and so on..
```

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

**NOTE** This is kind of a similar question I had asked earlier how ever somethings have changed and I can no longer use the same solution provided in the old question.

Comment: You should also tell us the technical reason why you can't use the old solution. Otherwise someone way offer a solution which depends on the same principles.

Comment: What's a variable? Is `MAX-ACCESS` a variable?

Comment: @terdon no it's not.

Comment: OK, so what is? Anything starting with a space and `copy`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
mapfile -t var < <(grep -Po '^\s+\K[^ ]+(?= ?\(\d+\),?$)' file.txt)
```

- `grep -P` will use PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression)
- `grep -o` will print the matched portion of the line
- `^\s+\K` will match the lines starting with whitespaces and `\K` will discard the match
- `[^ ]+` will match our desired portion
- `(?= *\(\d+\))` is the zero width positive look ahead pattern ensuring zero or one space followed by `(`, one or more digits, `)` and zero or one `,` at the end after our desired match
- `mapfile` is a shell built-in, used to create array.

  ```
  $ mapfile -t var < <(grep -Po '^\s+\K[^ ]+(?= ?\(\d+\),?$)' file.txt)

  $ echo "${var[0]}"
  copyOperationPending

  $ echo "${var[1]}"
  copyInProgress

  $ echo "${#var[@]}"
  19
  ```

Comment: +1, but may I suggest a simpler pattern? `\s+\K.*(?= ?\()`

Comment: @kos I have also think about this `grep -Po '\s*\K.*(?= ?\()' file.txt ` primarily..but OP's history is not so good to be honest hence this might well vary in several ways so taking no chances..  :)

Answer (score 3):

You can grep only the lines with the fields and use sed to remove everything after the opening parenthesis. The resulting list of words can be used directly to populate the array:

```
var=($(grep input-file ' *[a-zA-Z]\+ \?([0-9]\+)' | sed 's/(.*//'))
echo ${var[1]}
```

The regular expression used in grep is:

- space + `*`: any number of spaces (including 0)
- `[a-zA-Z]\+`: any number of letters (at least 1)
- space + `\?`: optional space
- `(`: left parenthesis
- `[0-9]\+`: any number of digits (at least 1)
- `)`: right parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

For the specific file you show, if you just want the strings starting with `copy`, it is enough to do:

```
var=( $(grep -o 'copy[^(]*' file) )
```

The you have:

```
$ for((i=0;i<${#var[@]};i++)); do echo "${var[i]}"; done
copyOperationPending
copyInProgress
copyOperationSuccess
copyInvalidOperation
copyInvalidProtocol
copyInvalidSourceName
copyInvalidDestName
copyInvalidServerAddress
copyDeviceBusy
copyDeviceOpenError
copyDeviceError
copyDeviceNotProgrammable
copyDeviceFull
copyFileOpenError
copyFileTransferError
copyFileChecksumError
copyNoMemory
copyUnknownFailure
copyInvalidSignature
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` method:

`ARRAY=($(awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "} /SYNTAX/ &&  /INTEGER/,/MAX-ACCESS/ {gsub(/SYNTAX|INTEGER|MAX-ACCESS.*|[[:blank:]]|{|}/,"");gsub(/\(/," (");for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {if ($i~/\(|\)/) $i="" };print}' testfile.txt))`

**Explanation**:

- We set up ARRAY=(…) structure, with command substitution $(…) within it to catch output of inner awk command into an array.
- Print everything from a line that has SYNTAX and INTEGER in it (to avoid cases where there's unknown amount of space between SYNTAX and INTEGER ) until MAX-ACCESS.
- delete words SYNTAX,INTEGER,MAX-ACCESS and whatever follows it, delete blank lines, and the two curly braces.
- Change the variables from variable(1) to variable (1) , i.e. separate them with space. At this point we have break those fields into two.
- Go through for loop to find fields that have curly braces and remove them. You may ask , what if the field contains spaces, like ( 1 ) or (1 ) ? Wouldn't that remove only (1 in the last example ? Well, we removed spaces before this step, so this should be safe.
- Finally print everything, space separated instead of default new-line for output record separator. All what's printed goes into array.

**Simplifying**

Let's put everything into an `awk` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{ORS=" "} 

/SYNTAX/ && /INTEGER/,/MAX-ACCESS/ {
   gsub(/SYNTAX|INTEGER|MAX-ACCESS.*|[[:blank:]]|{|}/,"");
   gsub(/\(/," (");
   for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {
        if ($i~/\(|\)/) $i="" 
   };
print }
```

Save make that script executable, and run like so:

```
$ ARRAY=($(./varscript.awk testfile.txt ))                                                                               


$ echo ${ARRAY[0]}
copyOperationPending


$ echo ${ARRAY[1]}                                                                                                       
copyInProgress


$ echo ${ARRAY[*]}                                                                                                       
copyOperationPending copyInProgress copyOperationSuccess copyInvalidOperation copyInvalidProtocol copyInvalidSourceName copyInvalidDestName copyInvalidServerAddress copyDeviceBusy copyDeviceOpenError copyDeviceError copyDeviceNotProgrammable copyDeviceFull copyFileOpenError copyFileTransferError copyFileChecksumError copyNoMemory copyUnknownFailure copyInvalidSignature
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk`

```
var=($(gawk '/{/,/}/ {if ($0 ~ /copy/) {match ($0, "[[:alpha:]]+", a); printf "%s\n",a[0]}}' <your_file>))
```

Using `perl`

```
var=($(perl -ne 'if (/copy/) {s/\s*([[:alpha:]]*).*/$1/g; printf "%s\n",$_}' <your_file>))
```

---

*Example*

`awk`

```
$ var=($(gawk '/{/,/}/ {if ($0 ~ /copy/) {match ($0, "[[:alpha:]]+", a); printf "%s\n",a[0]}}' foo))

$ for((i=0;i<${#var[@]};i++)); do echo "${var[i]}"; done
copyOperationPending
copyInProgress
copyOperationSuccess
copyInvalidOperation
copyInvalidProtocol
copyInvalidSourceName
copyInvalidDestName
copyInvalidServerAddress
copyDeviceBusy
copyDeviceOpenError
copyDeviceError
copyDeviceNotProgrammable
copyDeviceFull
copyFileOpenError
copyFileTransferError
copyFileChecksumError
copyNoMemory
copyUnknownFailure
copyInvalidSignature
```

`perl`

```
$ var=($(perl -ne 'if (/copy/) {s/\s*([[:alpha:]]*).*/$1/g; printf "%s\n",$_}' foo))

$ for((i=0;i<${#var[@]};i++)); do echo "${var[i]}"; done
copyOperationPending
copyInProgress
copyOperationSuccess
copyInvalidOperation
copyInvalidProtocol
copyInvalidSourceName
copyInvalidDestName
copyInvalidServerAddress
copyDeviceBusy
copyDeviceOpenError
copyDeviceError
copyDeviceNotProgrammable
copyDeviceFull
copyFileOpenError
copyFileTransferError
copyFileChecksumError
copyNoMemory
copyUnknownFailure
copyInvalidSignature
```

`cat foo`

```
ciscoFlashCopyStatus OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX  INTEGER
                {  
                copyOperationPending(0),
                copyInProgress(1),
                copyOperationSuccess (2),
                copyInvalidOperation (3),
                copyInvalidProtocol (4),
                copyInvalidSourceName (5),
                copyInvalidDestName (6),
                copyInvalidServerAddress (7),
                copyDeviceBusy (8),
                copyDeviceOpenError (9),
                copyDeviceError (10),
                copyDeviceNotProgrammable (11),
                copyDeviceFull (12),
                copyFileOpenError (13),
                copyFileTransferError(14),
                copyFileChecksumError(15),
                copyNoMemory (16),
                copyUnknownFailure(17),
                copyInvalidSignature(18)
                }
        MAX-ACCESS      read-only
        STATUS  current
```