# Remove whitespace from all array elements

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, awk

I have a array called `arrayvar`, which is being defined as

```
arrayvar=( $(awk '/'"$vovar"'/,/}/ {gsub("'"$vovar"'"," "); gsub("}"," "); gsub("{"," ");gsub(","," ");print}' temp1 | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed 's/[ \t]*$//') )
```

with

```
vovar=VARIABLES
```

My temp file has some variables which I am grabbing using the above command and the `tr` `sed` commands to remove spaces.
TEMP file

```
        ENTERPRISE eMylexRaidEventInformation
        VARIABLES {
            a9EventCode,
            a9ControllerNumber,
            a9ChannelNumber,
            a9TargetNumber,
            a9LunNumber,
            a9EventTimeStamp
        }
 DESCRIPTION
 "device became online."

 --#SUMMARY "[Event %d ctl %d chn %d tgt %d lun %d Time %d :] device became online."
 --#ARGUMENTS {0,1,2,3,4,5}
 --#SEVERITY INFORMATIONAL
         --#TIMEINDEX 5
 --#STATE OPERATIONAL
 ::= 1
```

When I run this command only `arrayvar[0]` is stripped of its values like this:

```
echo "${arrayvar[0]}"
a9EventCode

echo "${arrayvar[1]}"
            a9ControllerNumber

echo "${arrayvar[2]}"
            a9ChannelNumber

echo "${arrayvar[3]}"
            a9TargetNumber
```

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: you want to put the strings between `{` and `}` as array elements ?

Comment: yeah whatever is between the `{ }` brackets after `VARIABLES`. Warning , those strings may vary, they could all be in a single line, multiple strings in multiple line, only one string with in the `{}` and one string in one line (like the example above).  The `DESCRIPTION`  after `}` may or maynot be there. Same goes for `ENTERPRISE`. Only thing that separates the strings in the `{ }` are`,` . Which may not be there when we have only one string between { }.

Comment: You meant `a9EventCode, a9ControllerNumber` could be in a single line ? what would be the separator then ? also add some practical examples to your question you have mentioned in the comment..

Comment: @heemayl I had already asked this question before and muru gave me a solution, which works, however there are some extra spaces in each array element, that all I want to remove.  If you have a way to directly input these strings  without space then please help me out. [My Previous Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/642599/storing-some-strings-in-a-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
var=( $(< input awk '/VARIABLES {/, /}/ {if ($0~/VARIABLES/||$0~/}/) next; else gsub(/[ ,]/, "", $0); print}') )
```

- prints every record between a record matching `VARIABLES {` and a record matching `}`, removing every  and `,` character

However I'd rather use `mapfile` and a single fork in place of a double fork to store values into an array:

```
mapfile var < <(< input awk '/VARIABLES {/, /}/ {if ($0~/VARIABLES/||$0~/}/) next; else gsub(/[ ,]/, "", $0); print}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using later versions of GNU `grep` (comes with Ubuntu) that has `-z` option:

```
$ IFS=, arrayvar=( $(grep -Pzo '\s+VARIABLES\s+{\K[^}]+(?=})' temp1 | tr -d '[:space:]') )

$ echo "${arrayvar[0]}"
a9EventCode

$ echo "${arrayvar[1]}"
a9ControllerNumber

$ echo "${#arrayvar[@]}"
6
```

- `-z` option makes `grep` to treat the lines of input text separated by ASCII NUL instead of newlines so we can match newlines literally.
- The PCRE pattern `\s+VARIABLES\s+{\K[^}]+(?=})` will match the text inside `{}`
- Then we have removed the white spaces (space, tab, newline) by `tr -d '[:space:]'`
- As the `IFS` is set to `,` we can create the array with comma separated strings.

Answer (score 1):

Do everything with awk as below:

```
arrayvar=($(awk '/'"$vovar"'/,/}/ {gsub("'"$vovar"'"," "); gsub("}"," "); gsub("{"," ");gsub(","," ");all=all$0} END {print all}' temp1 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`

```
perl -ne 'exit if ($start == 1 && /}/ ); if ($start == 1) {s/\s*([0-9]|\w+)(,|)/$1/g; printf "%s",$_}; $start=1 if (/'"$vovar"'/);' <your_input_file>
```

---

*Explanation*

- `exit if ($start == 1 && /}/ );`

  Exit the script if there is an `}` if `VARIABLES` (`vovar`) is passed
- `if ($start == 1) {s/\s*([0-9]|\w+)(,|)/$1/g; printf "%s",$_}`

  Print the line if `VARIABLES` (`vovar`) is passed
- `$start=1 if (/'"$vovar"'/)`

  Set the start marker if `VARIABLES` (`vovar`) is passed

---

*Example*

```
$ vovar=VARIABLES
$ arrayvar=($(perl -ne 'exit if ($start == 1 && /}/ ); if ($start == 1) {s/\s*([0-9]|\w+)(,|)/$1/g; printf "%s",$_}; $start=1 if (/'"$vovar"'/);' foo))
$ for((i=0;i<${#arrayvar[@]};i++)); do echo "${arrayvar[i]}"; done
a9EventCode
a9ControllerNumber
a9ChannelNumber
a9TargetNumber
a9LunNumber
a9EventTimeStamp


$ cat foo
        ENTERPRISE eMylexRaidEventInformation
        VARIABLES {
            a9EventCode,
            a9ControllerNumber,
            a9ChannelNumber,
            a9TargetNumber,
            a9LunNumber,
            a9EventTimeStamp
        }
 DESCRIPTION
 "device became online."

 --#SUMMARY "[Event %d ctl %d chn %d tgt %d lun %d Time %d :] device became online."
 --#ARGUMENTS {0,1,2,3,4,5}
 --#SEVERITY INFORMATIONAL
         --#TIMEINDEX 5
 --#STATE OPERATIONAL
 ::= 1
```